# What's mandatory and what's not for the visual assets section of the app manifest for UWP/WPF projects?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, uwp

I'm wanting to submit an app to the store and I was wondering what pngs I'm meant to submit? I'm confused as there at least 60 different types of scales, for icons, splash screens, large tiles, wide tiles, small tiles. I'm almost overwhelmed with this information. Could someone give me a run through of what is required? for my app, I'm not wanting a small tile, or large tile, or any tile at all for that matter. So I'm seeking some answers as I am struggling to find resources outlining this specific case. I hope I've been clear enough; thanks.

**Is this all mandatory? What must I fill out?**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQAWU.png)

**Is this all mandatory for a splash screen?**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RKwh.png)

**Is this mandatory to fill out? What if I don't want any tiles, can I leave it as is?**
**[strong text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNH6A.png)**

Comment: If you want to submit a UWP app to the store, then it's better to get all the visual assets filled. You could select one picture that you want to use and generate all the other images via the Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-manual-conversion?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001077) for an example of a minimal required package manifest file for a desktop application.

You only need to reference a 150x150 (large) and 44x44 (small) icon image and I think you may use the same image if you want to.

Otherwise, there is a tool in Visual Studio that creates images of different sizes for you based on a single file.